# Does $f^{\ast}$ homotopic to $g^{\ast}$ imply $\int f^{\ast} w = \int g^{\ast} w$?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g: M^{k} \to N$ ($M$ and $N$ with out boundary ) such that they are homotopic then for $\omega$ a $k$-form on $N$ do we have that

$$ \int_M f^{\ast} \omega = \int_M g^{\ast} \omega$$

as conclusion? I  can't figure out a proof so I am starting to think that it is not true. I can't use Homology or Cohomology and all that fancy stuff . I think is just a matter of rearranging singular cubes but I can't see how.

The way I was trying to approach this is the following: Consider first
the case where support of $\omega$ is in the interior of the image of a singular cube $f \circ c$, where $c$ is a singular cube into $M$.

Then we look at the new singular cube $f \circ c : I \to N$. But I don't know what to do from here and how to approach the general case.

> **Attempt**

Using @TedShifrin's answer I've managed the following

$$\int_{M \times [0,1]}d(H^{*}w)=\int_{\partial(M \times [0,1])}H^{*}w = \int_{\partial M}g^{\ast}w-f^{\ast}w=0$$

but I am not sure.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You had better assume $M$ is a compact manifold without boundary and $\omega$ is a closed $k$-form on $N$. (The latter is automatic if $\dim N = k$ as well.) Then you can consider the homotopy mapping $H\colon M\times [0,1]\to N$ and apply Stokes's Theorem to $H^*\omega$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in that please ? Thanks

Comment: Write down Stokes's Theorem and think about what you know about $H$ on $\partial(M\times [0,1])$.

Comment: Yes sorry $M$ and $N$ are with out boundary :) let me edit but you need the differential form right?

Comment: Let me see your edition just a second :)

Comment: I don't understand. Unless you assume $d\omega = 0$ (that's what "closed" means), your statement is false. (Think of path-dependent line-integrals of $1$-forms along homotopic paths in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$, for example.) I had originally assumed (mistakenly) that $\dim N = k$, which would make any $k$-form on $N$ closed.

Comment: Ok so they key facts are closed form and manifolds with out boundary but how does that let me with the result because stokes theorem let you with zero on both sides right?

Comment: Yes, but follow up on my question in the second comment. You can figure this out.

Comment: With out assuming that the dimension of $N $ is $k$ would yield to the same result ?

Comment: So the "yes" is for the zero of the integrals or for the key facts ?

Comment: Then what do you say ?

Comment: So then can you clarify please ?

Comment: So then what do you say ?

Comment: I've edited my post :)

Comment: Is the edition right?

Comment: Draw a picture of $M\times [0,1]$, say, with $M=S^1$. What is the boundary? What you wrote cannot be right, since we already said that $M$ has no boundary. ...

Comment: Yes that is the thing first that I don't know how your "cartesian manifold" look like and second do we expect to have some subtraction as I wrote and conclude it is 0? Can you help wilt this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Work this out explicitly for $S^1\times [0,1]$, where you can certainly draw the picture. You also need to read about how you put an orientation on the *boundary* of a manifold with boundary. Surely this material is in your text.

Comment: Ok just give me some time right :) I'll be back

Answer (score 1):

Take $M=N=\mathbb R$ and take $\omega$ to be some nonvanishing $1$-form. Any two functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are homotopic to each other, hence all are homotopic to zero. If your claim were true it would imply that the integral of any $1$-form is zero, which of course is not the case!

What you might be thinking of is that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic then they induce the same map on de Rham complexes. In the previous example, I showed that *every* map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ induces zero as a function from the de Rham complex of $\mathbb R$ to itself. But because $\mathbb R$ is convex (or better, contractible) its de Rham cohomology vanishes! So we don't learn anything.

Comment: Ok so maybe we do need more stuff to prove the above right? Or what is your conclusion :)

Comment: Let me edit so I explain what were my thoughts on this right ?

Comment: Ready :) edition accomplished

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I think that the answer to the original question you asked is "no", and I don't see a new question . . .

Comment: Is not a new question, the thing is that I have written what I expected to do so may be is clearer what where my question is going :)

Comment: Thanks for the edition :) so then is it clear now?

Comment: Then what can be done ?

Comment: I've edited my post :)